# Unable to view embed HTML on published page WordPress Elementor (working fine in editor)

Tags: wordpress, embed, elementor, wistia

I’m having trouble viewing my embedded HTML container with a video from Wistia on my published page (working fine in editor).

I can listen to the video´s audio, but I can´t see the video itself in the page...

Here are a few details:

- Website:
  https://portugalsaude.rf.gd/upalemsono/
- Video´s embed code:

```html
<div class="wistia_responsive_padding" style="padding:75.0% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><div class="wistia_responsive_wrapper" style="height:100%;left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;"><iframe src="https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/9skkqkkoou?seo=true&videoFoam=true" title="VSL Alem do Sono Part 1 Video" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" msallowfullscreen width="100%" height="100%"></iframe></div></div>
<script src="https://fast.wistia.net/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>
```

Many thanks in advance!
Caio

Embed a Wistia video in my Wordpress page.